# Force unused function to export in shared library

Tags: c++, gcc

printme() and getme() defined in top.cpp and top.h

I used printme() function in test.cpp (test cpp file) in main function

```
g++34 -c top.cpp -fPIC    
ar rcs libtop.a top.o    
g++34 -c test.cpp -fPIC

g++34 -shared -o ltop.so -ltop -L. -fPIC
```

getme is not getting exported in ltop.so

How i can force getme function exported in ltop.so
When i do nm ltop.so
it is not showing getme symbol
i want to force this

Note: file can have multiple unused function like - getme()
I want to force all to export to **so** library

Answer (score 2):

Don't use your static library to create your dynamic one. Instead, use the component object file directly:

```
g++34 -shared -o ltop.so -fPIC top.o
```

The reason is that when you specify a library with `-l` when compiling a binary, only unresolved external symbols from earlier in the compilation line are picked up. In your case, this is nothing, so precisely nothing is picked up in creating `libtop.so` from `libtop.a`

**UPDATE:** As an alternative, if the original object files are no longer available, youc an use the `--whole-archive` linker option to force it to include everything from a static library, rather than just unresolved externals:

```
g++34 -shared -o ltop.so -fPIC -Wl,--whole-archive ./libtop.a
```

Or:

```
g++34 -shared -o ltop.so -fPIC -Wl,--whole-archive -L. -ltop
```

Comment: @Smeehey I have only static library for now.  Question detail has just an example of scenario.

Answer (score 2):

Normally, when linking with a static library only the modules in the static library that contain an unresolved symbol end up getting linked.

Here, since there is no unresolved reference to `getme`(), hence this module does not get linked from the static library. The solution is to explicitly make it unresolved.

A minor complicating factor is the C++ symbol name mangling. It is necessary to figure out what is the mangled symbol name for the `getme()` function. The easiest way is to look at the library with the `nm` command:

```
$ nm libtop.a

top.o:
0000000000000000 T _Z5getmei
```

Ok, so the mangled symbol name is `_Z5getmei`. The `-u` linker flag forces an unresolved reference to the indicated symbol to be used when linking:

```
g++ -shared -o ltop.so -L. -ltop -Wl,-u -Wl,_Z5getmei
```

The documentation for the `-u` option is found in the `ld` man page. This includes the module in the shared library:

```
$ nm ltop.so | grep getme
0000000000000680 T _Z5getmei
```

Comment: I want a general way to do this, not checking individual function reference and then pass with g++ command.

Comment: That's why it is very important to ask a precise question. Otherwise, people will be wasting their time coming up with an answer that does not address the real question. Should've at least titled the question "forcing inclusion of all modules into a shared library", instead of explicitly stating that this is about just one "unused function".